# How to write a very simple wrapper that provides default parameters?

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

Given a program that requires some parameters, e.g. `program -in file.in -out file.out`, what would be the simple-most approach to write a bash script that could be called with or without any of these parameters and use default values for each?

`script -in otherfile` would run `program -in otherfile -out file.out`,
`script -out otherout -furtherswitch` would run `program -in file.in -out otherout -furtherswitch` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A default value is easy to define in Bash:

```
foo="${bar-default}" # Sets foo to the value of $bar if defined, "default" otherwise
foo="${bar:-default}" # Sets foo to the value of $bar if defined or empty, "default" otherwise
```

To process your parameters, you can use a simple loop:

```
while true
do
    case "${1-}" in
        -in)
            infile="${2-}"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -out)
            outfile="${2-}"
            shift 2
            ;;
        *)
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

program -in "${infile-otherfile}" -out "${outfile-otherout}" "$@"
```

Useful reads:

- [Parameter handling](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters)
- [Passing parameters to another script](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

I also recommend using `getopt` instead, because it is able to handle many special cases which would very quickly complicate and clutter your code ([Non-trivial example](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/e48ba0c2c892ac2426a1e6b6e5f9930253398b70/scripts/make-links.sh#L67-L126)).

Comment: Thanks! A `while $# -gt 0` (or similar) and `*) others="${others-} $1"; shift 1 ;; ` would survive other parameters before the default-able ones. But maybe I should learn `getopt` instead...

Comment: Of course I could also simply write a python script...

Answer (score 3):

l0b0's answer shows how to set a default value through assignment and checking another variable's state (although, of course, you can also do this operating on the same variable you are assigning to), but there is a more concise way to do the same thing:

```
: "${foo=bar}" # $foo = bar if $foo is unset
: "${foo:=bar}" # $foo = bar if $foo is unset or empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways, as usual, simple and hard. Simple is to use inner variables, for example

```
program -in otherfile -out file.out
```

Here variable are

$0 = The script name
   $1 = -in
   $2 = otherfile, etc.

The Hard way is to use `getopt`, more information you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options).

Comment: Using `$1` etc will fail if I omit parameters, and manually parsing them would be annoying. Is there no midway between that and [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt)?

Answer (score 1):

- Pass all parameters (`$*`) passed to `script` to `program` too
- Check each parameter you interested, if it's already in parameters passed, then ignore it. otherwise use default parameter value

**Sample code**

```
interested_parameter_names=(-in -out)
default_parameter_values=(file.in file.out)

program=echo
cmd="$program $*"

for ((index=0; index<${#interested_parameter_names[*]}; index++))
do
    param="${interested_parameter_names[$index]}"
    default_value="${default_parameter_values[$index]}"
    if [ "${*#*$param}" == "$*" ]   # if $* not contains $param
    then
        cmd="$cmd $param $default_value"
    fi
done

echo "command line will be:"
echo "$cmd"

echo
echo "execute result:"
$cmd
```

You can easily add more default parameters/values by add more array element in `$interested_parameter_names` and `$default_parameter_values`

**Sample output**

```
$ ./wrapper.sh -in non-default.txt -other-params
command line will be:
echo -in non-default.txt -other-params -out file.out

execute result:
-in non-default.txt -other-params -out file.out
```

**Note**

When passing parameters which contains space, it should be escaped by `\`, not just quoted them. Example:

```
./script -in new\ document.txt
```

Comment: Neat! I think the quotes issue can be solved by using `$@` instead of `$*`. What does `${*#*$param}` do?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, `"${*#*$param}" == "$*"` is used to check if `$*` NOT contains `$param`, it's [**Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern** parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Comment: `./script -in new\ document.txt` would not work, and there's not way to make it work with that flawed approach. By concatenating the arguments into a string, you're losing the information about how those arguments are separated.